# Why isn't my Google OAuth 2.0 Working?

Tags: php, oauth, youtube-api, google-oauth

I've been working on a small script to grab YouTube channel data and my Google OAuth 2.0 isn't working.

```
$validate = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=242340718758-65veqhhdjfl21qc2klkfhbcb19rre8li.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://conor1998.web44.net/php/oauth.php&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly&response_type=code&access_type=offline";

echo "<a href='$validate'>Login with Google for advanced analytics</a>";

if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
    // try to get an access token
    $code = $_GET['code'];
    $url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?code='.$code.'&client_id=242340718758-65veqhhdjfl21qc2klkfhbcb19rre8li.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={secret}&redirect_uri=http://conor1998.web44.net/php/oauth.php&grant_type=authorization_code';
    $url = urlencode($url);
    header('Location: $url');
}


$response = file_get_contents($url);
$response = json_decode($response);



$channel_data = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel==mine&start-date=2014-08-01&end-date=2014-09-01&metrics=views&key=AIzaSyDTxvTLWXStUrhzgCDptVUG4dGBCpyL9MY?alt=json');
$channel_data = json_decode($channel_data, true);

echo "<br />";
var_dump($channel_data);
echo "<br />";
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work. I feel it's mainly due to my goal of trying to get the authentication token for the user so i can grab their YouTube data. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The code you receive from the auth website is not the access token! You have to [exchange it for refresh and access tokens](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication#server-side-apps) (see #4).

You have to perform a POST request to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token in order to get your tokens. It is not working via GET (as you can see when clicking the link).